# Photo's vector characteristic

Tags: photons, gauge-invariance

In Frank Close's *infinity puzzle*, it says that to maintain the invariance for electric charge requires some means to transmit information about the local charge of gauge to electric charges elsewhere. Local gauge invariance requires the agent that is carrying this information from one electron to another to be a massless particle, which has a sense of direction-hence known as a "vector". We know that the agent is photon, what is this vector characteristic of photon?

Comment: The photon is a [vector boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_boson)